# How to write podspec file's source_files pattern to download .hh file while using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, zxing

I want to use cocoapods to install [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), but some .hh file can not be downloaded, what I write is something like this:

```
s.source_files                = 'cpp/core/src/zxing/**/*.hh', 'cpp/core/src/zxing/**/*.h', 'cpp/core/src/zxing/**/*.cpp', 'objc/src/ZXing/*.{m,mm}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out to be my networking problem that leads to some files haven't been downloaded, so the syntax of my sources_file pattern is right.